Can I setup Freestyle to get line width depending on local light value of an object?
I'm looking for a way to use Freestyle to mimic an illustration technique to depict volume in a line drawing.
I learned to use line width to guide the viewer into thinking they're looking at an object with volume.
Imagine a ball and a light shining onto it from the top left corner.
I'd draw a black circle outline with a thin line at 'eleven o'clock' and a wide line at 'four o'clock'.
Example: https://mediviz.nl/nu/blender/SphereLine.png
How can Freestyle be setup in a way that if it is an outline and it has a slope of 60 deg and the object is to the upper left -> thick line. And object is to the lower right -> thin line.
Or:
Freestyle outline. Local shade of gray object is light -> thin line and local shade of grey object is dark -> thick line.

Hello, please include pictures/a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

:( I mixed Grease Pensil with an effect I'd like to achieve with Freestyle...
https://mediviz.nl/nu/blender/SphereLine.png is an example.
I'll rephrase my question..
